# How to create alert message with media-object behaviour?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create alert info message with media-object behaviour.

I mean this behaviour:

[image]

There is image on the left side of the alert and text on the another side.

What I've tried?

I am getting this:

[image]

With such code:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">                                                                                                 
    <div class="media">                                                                                                        
        <span class="pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>                                                   
        <div class="media-body">                                                                                               
            <p>string1</p><p>string2</p><p>string3</p>
        </div>                                                                                                                 
    </div>                                                                                                                     
</div>
```

But glyphicon is too small. I need bigger glyphicon here. How I can make icon bigger or what approach should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped:

```
<div class="media">                                                                                                                             
    <span class="pull-left lg glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>                                                                            
    <div class="media-body">                                                                                                                    
        <p>Статус договора <em>действует</em> означает, что Вы можете сделать заказ на поставку у данного поставщика.</p>                       
        <p>В таблице встречаются строки разных цветов. Зеленый цвет означает, что договор действующий, а серый — срок действия истек.</p>       
    </div>                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

Also, class `.lg` specified in css:

```
.lg {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I could get:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Sx62/

Basically, I wrapped icon with `.media-object` div, the docs says that it shouldn't be mixed with other components. Then, I increased font-size so icon would be bigger